# how to prevent buttons with same class from executing at the same time with jquery

Tags: jquery

It may be once again a simple question, but I am spending already quite some hours figuring this out, so if you could help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.

I have a script that generates a list of applicants for a certain group. Every applicant has his/her own little "business card" with some concise info about him or her. Also there are two buttons on the business card; 1 to put the candidate on a shortlist and one to reject the application. Problem now is that once you click on ONE shortlist button, the jquery code runs on ALL of the buttons in the list. This makes sense as they are all of the same class (button15) because generated within a PHP variable. Also it adds not the selected one, but the bottom candidate to the shortlist.

What I would like to know is how to prevent all the buttons running the code when I click on one button? Here is the code that generates this mishap:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button15').click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "shortlist.php?u=<?php echo $_applicant;?>&n=<?php echo $_name;?>&h=<?php echo $_colhead; ?>",
            data : "dataString",
            beforeSend : function() {
                var exhtml = $('.msg').html();
                $('.msg').html("<img src='../Images/animated gif tapebar.gif'/>").delay(1000);
            },
            success : function(html){
                var responsetext = "<?php echo $_applicant;?> has been added to the shortlist.";
                $('.button15').fadeOut("slow");
                $('.button14').fadeOut("slow");
                $('.msg').html(responsetext).delay( 800 ).fadeIn("slow");

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

This is the corrected code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button15').click(function(e) {
        var self = this;
        var a = ($(this).attr('id'));
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "shortlist.php?u=" + a + "&n=<?php echo $_name;?>&h=<?php echo $_colhead; ?>",
            data : "dataString",
            beforeSend : function() {
                var exhtml = $('.msg').html();
                $(self).siblings('.msg').html("<img src='http://files.domain.com/Images/animated gif tapebar.gif'/>").delay(1000);
            },
            success : function(html){
                var responsetext = "You have successfully added " + a + " to the shortlist.";
                $(self).fadeOut("slow");
                $('.button14').fadeOut("slow");
                $(self).siblings('.msg').html(responsetext).fadeIn("slow");
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What makes you say the code is executing for all buttons? What is the symptom of the problem you're seeing?

Comment: What it does is: I click on one button of the list and all the other buttons act like I clicked on them - running the loader gif at the same time, coming all back with the same result: the last one in the list has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to act only to the current element using this your are fading all the button15 elements.

Try to take a reference of the current element this like:

```
var self = this;
```

and use it in the success function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button15').click(function(e) {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "shortlist.php?u=<?php echo $_applicant;?>&n=<?php echo $_name;?>&h=<?php echo $_colhead; ?>",
            data : "dataString",
            beforeSend : function() {
                var exhtml = $('.msg').html();
                $(self).siblings('.msg').html("<img src='../Images/animated gif tapebar.gif'/>").delay(1000);
            },
            success : function(html){
                var responsetext = "<?php echo $_applicant;?> has been added to the shortlist.";
                $('.button15').fadeOut("slow");
                $('.button14').fadeOut("slow");
                $(self).siblings('.msg').html(responsetext).delay( 800 ).fadeIn("slow");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

but I don't know what `button14` and `msg` elements are...I think they are linked to the current element too...

### EDIT

Instead of change all the `msg` elements find only the sibling of the current element using `$(self).siblings('.msg')`; code in the answer changed accordingly.

Comment: Button 14 is the reject button, but that has no function atm. msg is the span that holds the response. What happens is that when I click for example the 3rd candidate and all the business cards show "please wait" at the same time - they just do everything the clicked button does all at the same time. I do appreciate that the fade fades all the buttons and this can be removed as it's not important. Hope this makes things a bit more clear. Thanks so far!

Comment: But msg span is a child/sibling of the clicked element?

Comment: I am currently at work, so I won't be able to look at it before I get home tonight. Will do so and check back with you. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes! This is working! A little fiddling with the id of the button (made the variable $_applicant the id for the button) and it does exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much Irvin/Edward - spent days on this and I just couldn't get my head around it, but now it works :) Just one little question: I added the correct code into my original post - can I make the other button (button14 - the reject button) disappear in a similar way as the clicked button? Everybody who contributed a big Guinness Thank You for your efforts from Ireland :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't think your problem is with the Jquery, but your

```
url  : "shortlist.php?u=<?php echo $_applicant;?>&n=<?php echo $_name;?>&h=<?php echo $_colhead; ?>"
```

It doesn't matter which button you will click the values in $_applicant, $_name and $_colhead are identical for all buttons.

Also,

```
$('.button15').fadeOut("slow");
$('.button14').fadeOut("slow");
```

will fade out all buttons15 and 14

One way of doing what you're trying to do is

1. Save Applicant, Name and and ColHead into a hidden field for Each Applicant. Give those fields Unique IDs. Example Applicant_1 ="Bob", Applicant_2 ="Jane"
2. Each Accept buttons would have a unique ID as well (Example: 1)
3. In your Click Event. Get the ID of the button and lookup the Applicant_+id.
4. Execute the Ajax with correct data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to my question, and assuming that an element with classname msg corresponds to each button, I believe the culprit is these two lines:

```
                $('.msg').html("<img src='../Images/animated gif tapebar.gif'/>").delay(1000);

                $('.msg').html(responsetext).delay( 800 ).fadeIn("slow");
```

In both cases, try changing `$('.msg')` to `$(this).find('.msg')`. Basically, I think the rest of the code is fine, your selectors are just too general for the .msg elements.